# Detect XHR request

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'd like to fire a function when the site does a XHR request. I have tried many suggestions posted on stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work for my userscript. So I decided to ask it myself. Hopefully you can help.

The function I want to call uses GM_setValue and GM_getValue, so that makes it also more difficult.
I also tried the function below and similar functions, but it only works when using it in the JavaScript console. When I use it with a userscript it doesn't work anymore...
I've also tried waitForKeyElements, but that doesn't seem to work for me.
And setTimeout and setInterval is not really an option.
Please help. Thanks in advance!

```
var oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;
function newXHR() {
    var realXHR = new oldXHR();
    realXHR.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if(realXHR.readyState==4 && realXHR.status==200){
            afterAjaxComplete() //run your code here
        }
    }, false);
    return realXHR;
}
window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the default `XMLHttpRequest` methods with custom ones, and catch the needed events:

```
var open = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
  send = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

function openReplacement(method, url, async, user, password) {
  this._url = url;
  return open.apply(this, arguments);
}

function sendReplacement(data) {
  if(this.onreadystatechange) {
    this._onreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;
  }
  this.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChangeReplacement;
  return send.apply(this, arguments);
}

function onReadyStateChangeReplacement() {

  //YOUR CODE FOR READYSTATECHANGE

  if(this._onreadystatechange) {
    return this._onreadystatechange.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = openReplacement;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = sendReplacement;
```

**Update**: [read this post](http://rainsoft.io/catch-the-xmlhttp-request-in-plain-javascript/) for more info on the approach and examples.

Comment: Thanks! At first it seemed to work, but sadly there are still some problems.

When there are multiple XHR requests, my function only calls after the first one. (Not a big problem)

And it doesn't seem to detect the page changes after the XHR request.
For example, I'm using this piece of code in my function:
`document.documentElement.innerHTML.match(/xxx/g)`
But it doesn't detect the new matches added by the XHR request.

Comment: @Royalgamer06 Well it works perfectly in my production app. What kind of problems?

Comment: sorry I hit enter before I was done writing. Check first comment.

Comment: Hmm, the problems I mentioned before is only for certain sites.

Comment: You need to use the following code only once, and attach your custom handlers.

Comment: I still have the above problems with certain sites, but it seems like most sites work! Thanks a lot!!
It's good enough for me, and its a personal script. :)